# Drop rows with gps coordinates which are too close to each other

Tags: python, pandas, gps, coordinates, geopandas

I have a huge dataset with lat/lon coordinates and some features (data from public transport vehicle). My purpose is to find a number of traffic lights on a route. The problem is, that the data structure doesn't allow to get separate routes and I have to operate with the whole dataset which covers several months and has secondwise granularity. Every public transport unit makes several trips per day. That means that for one traffic light I have a lot of gps-coordinates which are only few meters one from another. And the task is to reduce this amount of gps-coordinates so I get only ONE coordinte-pair for ONE traffic light. I made some steps and now I have dataframe which looks this way:

```
    data = {'date': ['2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18',
                 '2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-18','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04',
                 '2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04','2021-10-04'],
    'time': ['04:55:55','04:57:20','04:57:47','04:57:56','04:58:06','04:59:59','05:00:57','05:02:06','05:02:49','05:03:15','05:04:01','05:04:26','05:04:49','05:05:06','05:06:42','05:07:39',
             '05:08:52', '05:09:39','05:09:45','05:10:48','04:33:02','04:33:30','04:33:40','04:33:50', '04:35:44', '04:36:50', '04:38:05', '04:38:55', '04:39:27', '04:40:14', '04:40:39','04:40:48',
             '04:41:03', '04:42:03', '04:42:58', '04:43:55', '04:44:48', '04:44:55', '04:45:23', '04:45:42'],
        'intersection': ['intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light',
                         'intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light','intersection with traffic light'],
      'longitude': [12.39476,12.39273139,12.39165194,12.39082944,12.39048889,12.38607694,12.384235,12.38217306,12.38082611,12.377815,12.37579417,12.37344,12.37324472,12.37328833,12.37339389,
                    12.37346444,12.37354778,12.37365694,12.37367139,12.37369528,12.39270917,12.39166111,12.39082972,12.39049861,12.38609611,12.38424417,12.38213278,12.38081778,12.37780417,12.37576306,
                    12.37338806,12.37325139,12.37328833,12.3733425,12.37341,12.37349139,12.37359806,12.37361,12.3736375,12.37372528],
      'latitude': [51.28439083,51.28715778,51.28938389,51.29012778,51.29072139,51.29580667,51.30110722,51.30425417,51.30640389,51.30806056,51.3088925,51.3099825,51.31048111,51.31150611,
                   51.3147425,51.31745667,51.32047083,51.32413,51.32455833,51.32514389,51.28719056,51.28937667,51.2901275,51.29070417,51.29577389,51.30108056,51.30431,51.30641833,51.30806444,51.30890833,
                   51.31002389,51.31054167,51.31151028,51.31470833,51.31748917,51.32046694,51.32410833,51.32452333,51.32514528,51.3266075],
        'measure': [0.58,46.11,59.51,4.93,22.51,-58.49,97.24,6.27,6.12,5.98,5.97,5.98,5.91,6.12,5.98,64.76,252.86,134.51,198.99,4.71,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.6,1.6,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.6,1.6,1.6,
                    1.6,0.0,0.0,0.0],
       'distance': [0.0, 338.80883546503435,258.8586443913898,100.70483527232803,70.18422302767863,644.0439236587058,603.5386497851093,378.4917854757065,256.9494020292987,279.3917492835428,
                    168.5934711941755,204.0901046994475,57.11922120985705,114.0761160032451,360.13741023688664,302.003203591515,335.38882347626014,407.1700274516668,47.664275824026944,65.16745993800518,342.7123292169329,
                    253.96517553235194,101.69272687297509,68.18793453494897,642.2083802222841,604.3526349828485,388.29131154667175,251.84909010340672,278.74949164225853,170.5056375968028,206.95284289377074,
                    58.38815419745605,107.79273387770405,355.81675100197504,309.41626170998205,331.33853649772004,405.18904714111363,46.17811034656468,69.22127740066063,162.7935968085381]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df
```

What I did: first, took only first rows, where a change in column `intersection` occured. Then took only `'intersection with traffic light'` and calculated distances between consecutive points with `geopy.distance`. So, based on distance I can filter out gps-coordinates which are within e.g. 50 meters from each other. But it doesn't solve my problem and I think  it is a wrong approach. I guess, I should create a matrix with distances of all points to each other, e.g. with `cdist` and based on that matrix filter all redundant gps-coordinates. Or it should be another way? Please advice!

**UPDATE1** I add a kepler visualisation of the problem, so you can see: from this bunch of points I only need to get one for one intersection with traffic light[image]
**UPDATE2** I made this example df bit bigger, so with kepler visualisation you can see at least 2 gps-points per one intersection (and I have to deal like with avg 50 gps-points for 1 intersection). Here's code for kepler visualisation

```
    from keplergl import KeplerGl
    map_exmpl=KeplerGl(height=800, width=600)
    # Create a gepdataframe
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude))
    map_exmpl.add_data(data=gdf)
    map_exmpl
```

Comment: I don't understand in your dataset where are your different routes?

Comment: In this small dataset you can't see it. I will add a visualisation to the question so it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I've understood the problematic.
Let's say you want to filter all the firecross with distance <= 70 m.

You can apply this code :

```
_condition = (df.distance<=70) & (df.distance!=0)

df['duplicate'] = np.where(_condition,np.nan,df.distance)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df
```

Then, all the rows with firecross with distance <70 will be droped.

### EDIT 1

An other approach is to define a round of coordinates which are too close to belong to different fire cross.
Let's say, for the example, that we want to approximate it to 2 digits.

```
df['longitude'] = df.longitude.values.round(2)
df['latitude'] = df.latitude.values.round(2)
df = df[df.index.isin(df[['longitude','latitude']].drop_duplicates().index.to_list())].copy()
```

Comment: I updated my question. I guess, it could be also done with `df[df.distance<70]`. But it's not what I need. The final aim is to get only one gps-coordinate for one intersection instead of e.g. 50 - say, keep only 1 coordinate pair and delete other 49 whithin 50-70m radius

Comment: O, sorry, I didn't catch it. Do you mean that all the coordinates in the example are approximatively designing the same firecross?

Comment: In the example I added another day, so you can see, that for every intersection I have at least 2 coordinate pairs (there are 20 intersections in this example). Imagine I have more days and months - then I get a bunch of coordinate-pairs for the same intersection like about 50, which lie close to each other. And I need only one unique x,y-coordinate pair for one intersection

Comment: to another approach: here I have to be careful with rounding, because distances between intersections are also short, e.g. 200 m. So if I round to the 3d decimal, I'll get too little points, and for the 4th decimal - too much

Comment: O, ok. Sorry if I'm long for understanding. Now, I think that I got it! Let say that a bus is doing a route several time a day, and several day per week/month/etc etc. The measure are taken during the route. Your obejctive is to determine the number of traffic light, BUT, there are duplicates because the bus is doing the same route. And some of dupplicates havn't got the exact same gps cord. because they don't stop exactly at the same point. That's it? So you could combien the two approaches, no?